# jQuery Arrow Key reader

Tags: jquery

Hi there, I am using this site http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#callback-functions jQuery for selecting an image, even though when I select an image I do get the coordinates, but I don't get the coordinates when I use the arrow key from the keyboard to move the selection around. any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a (non-)working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: here is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/hUg76/, it works fine with the mouse but when I move the select area around, it doesnt give me back any kind of coordination

Comment: I can't get it to work with keyboard, so I'll just leave the correct [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hUg76/1/) so it will be easy for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it fixed. Your code is right, I didnt need Key{ture ..} stuff

Comment: I posted it as a answer, so please accept it if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work with keyboard, so I'll just leave you with a fixed jsfiddle with working selection.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#duck').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        onSelectEnd: function(img, selection) {
            $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hUg76/1/)